# Kotlin/Native How to include C-interop headers in the artifact?

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, cinterop

I've added the headers like so in the `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
linuxX64 {
    val main by compilations.getting
    main.cinterops.create("x11") {
        defFile("src/linuxX64Main/cinterop/x11.def")
        compilerOpts.add("-I" + rootDir.resolve("include"))
    }
}
```

Library compiles fine, and published to mavenLocal fine, but when some other project add it as a dependency and runs the linker, it produces the following errors:

```kotlin
> Task :linkReleaseExecutableLinuxX64
e: C:\Users\Animesh\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/ld.lld invocation reported errors
The C:\Users\Animesh\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/ld.lld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: XOpenDisplay
>>> referenced by out
>>>               C:\Users\Animesh\AppData\Local\Temp\konan_temp3813013133705122841\result.o:(kfun:com.github.animeshz.keyboard.X11KeyboardHandler#prepare(){})
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: XPeekEvent
>>> referenced by out
>>>               C:\Users\Animesh\AppData\Local\Temp\konan_temp3813013133705122841\result.o:(kfun:com.github.animeshz.keyboard.X11KeyboardHandler#readEvents(){})
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: XCloseDisplay
>>> referenced by out
>>>               C:\Users\Animesh\AppData\Local\Temp\konan_temp3813013133705122841\result.o:(kfun:com.github.animeshz.keyboard.X11KeyboardHandler#cleanup(){})
> Task :linkReleaseExecutableLinuxX64 FAILED
```

How do we include some C-interop headers/symbols in the library artifact that is to be built and published to maven (currently testing on mavenLocal)?

Comment: Am I getting it right you want to pack the shared library into the resulting artifact? Why not try to generate bindings for a library installed in the target system instead?